# Could we use design tokens ("defaultTokens" file) in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-web-components, design-tokens

Is there any possibility to apply design tokens ("defaultTokens" file) in Visualforce pages so if I change value of some token in "defaultTokens", this changes the style on the Visualforce page as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visualforce, all you can use are included CSS files (static CSS). It is not possible to use Design Tokens in Visualforce. If you wanted to take advantage of this, you could use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm) and display a Lightning Component on the page.